# Make a TDBEdit show the characters remaining

Tags: delphi

The problem I'm wanting to solve is to display to the user the remaining characters left in a field as they are typing into a TDBEdit.

Currently I'm doing something along the lines of

```
lCharRemaining.Caption := Field.Size - length(dbedit.text);
```

i.e. updating a label in the OnChange event for the TDBEdit, which works perfectly fine.  However I'm wanting to do this for a number of TDBEdits and tried to write a custom component that would display the length remaining within the edit box on the right.  It however interferes with editing.  I was perhaps thinking that I could display a hint while someone was typing indicating the remaining space in the field - any suggestions?

Here is the code for my component (if someone can suggest improvements).

```
unit DBEditWithLenghtCountdown;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Mask, DBCtrls, messages, Graphics;

type
  TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown = class(TDBEdit)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function CharactersRemaining : integer;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  db, Types;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown]);
end;

{ TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown }

function TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.CharactersRemaining: integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  if Assigned(Field)then
  begin
    result := Field.Size - Length(Text);
  end;
end;

constructor TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
end;

destructor TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.Destroy;
begin
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  R: TRect;
  Remaining : string;
  WidthOfText: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if not focused then
    exit;


  Remaining := IntToStr(CharactersRemaining);
  R := ClientRect;
  Inc(R.Left, 1);
  Inc(R.Top, 1);
  Canvas.Brush.Assign(Self.Brush);
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
  Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;

  WidthOfText := Canvas.TextWidth(Remaining);
  x := R.right - WidthOfText - 4;
  Canvas.TextOut(x,2, Remaining);
end;

procedure TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited WndProc(Message);
  with Message do
    case Msg of
      CM_MOUSEENTER, CM_MOUSELEAVE, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
      WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP,
      WM_SETFOCUS, WM_KILLFOCUS,
      CM_FONTCHANGED, CM_TEXTCHANGED:
      begin
        Invalidate;
      end;
   end; // case
end;

end.
```

Comment: How does it "interfere with the editing?"  You essentially just said "it doesn't work," which is the least useful phrase in the history of debugging.  What goes wrong when you try to do it?

Comment: @MasonWheeler The remaining length text overwrites what is currently being typed as you approach the end of the edit box.

Comment: But why do you want to have a new component? It could be generalized for all classes derived from TCustomEdit

Comment: In which Delphi version are you working? I just made a test in XE2, including @Sertac improvement, and it works as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test how it would look like without any text interference by setting the edit margins to leave space for the tip text. A quick test:

```
type
  TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown = class(TDBEdit)
    ..
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas;
    ..


procedure TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.CreateWnd;
var
  MaxWidth, Margins: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  MaxWidth := Canvas.TextWidth('WW');
  Margins := Perform(EM_GETMARGINS, 0, 0);
  Margins := MakeLong(HiWord(Margins), LoWord(Margins) + MaxWidth);
  Perform(EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN or EC_RIGHTMARGIN, Margins);
end;
```

Beyond this is personal opinion but I find this a bit confusing. What I would do is probably publish a status panel field on the derived edit, and output some text to it if it is assigned when the text of the edit control changes.

**edit:** Here's a somewhat extended version that should take care of the issue mentioned in the comment (if navigate left with a long text, edit text overwrites tip text), and also sets margins only if the control has focus. (Not full code duplicated from the question, only modified bits.)

```
type
  TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown = class(TDBEdit)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    FTipWidth: Integer;
    FDefMargins: Integer;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  protected
    ..


procedure TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  PaintStruct: TPaintStruct;
  EndPaint: Boolean;
  Rgn: HRGN;
  R, TipR: TRect;
  Remaining : string;
begin
  if not Focused then
    inherited
  else begin
    EndPaint := Message.Dc = 0;
    if Message.DC = 0 then
      Message.DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PaintStruct);

    R := ClientRect;
    TipR := R;
    TipR.Left := TipR.Right - FTipWidth;
    Remaining := IntToStr(CharactersRemaining);
    Canvas.Handle := Message.DC;
    SetBkColor(Canvas.Handle, ColorToRGB(Color));
    Canvas.Font := Font;
    Canvas.Font.Color :=  clRed;
    Canvas.TextRect(TipR, Remaining, [tfSingleLine, tfCenter, tfVerticalCenter]);

    R.Right := TipR.Left;
    Rgn := CreateRectRgn(R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
    SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, Rgn);
    DeleteObject(Rgn);
    inherited;
    if EndPaint then
      windows.EndPaint(Handle, PaintStruct);
  end;
end;

procedure TDBEditWithLenghtCountdown.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
const
  TipMargin = 3;
begin
  inherited WndProc(Message);
  with Message do
    case Msg of
      CM_MOUSEENTER, CM_MOUSELEAVE, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
      WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP,
      CM_TEXTCHANGED: Invalidate;
      WM_CREATE: FDefMargins := Perform(EM_GETMARGINS, 0, 0);
      CM_FONTCHANGED:
        begin
          Canvas.Handle := 0;
          Canvas.Font := Font;
          FTipWidth := Canvas.TextWidth('67') + 2 * TipMargin;
        end;
      WM_SETFOCUS:
        Perform(EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN or EC_RIGHTMARGIN,
            MakeLong(HiWord(FDefMargins), LoWord(FDefMargins) + FTipWidth));
      WM_KILLFOCUS:
        Perform(EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN or EC_RIGHTMARGIN, FDefMargins);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: This is a big improvement usability wise, and works great when you are adding to the end of the TDBEdit, but if you are editing the middle, or the cursor is at the beginning the text still overwrites (underwrites?) the numbers.

Comment: @Alister - I think you'd like to remove the line setting 'bsClear' to Canvas.Brush.Style in WM_PAINT handler, alternatively fill a background rectangle before your TextOut.

Comment: @Alister - Updated code to suggest a solution for the *underwrite*.

Comment: Very nice, solution accepted - although I also like the Sir Rufo's idea of using a bar which I have incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a base for you to start with, if do not want to derive every Edit-Component, here is a general approach for every Component derived from TCustomEdit.

Set the MaxLength of the Edit-Component to a Value > 0 and this Unit will paint you a thin red line below the text as a fill indicator.

The Unit has only to be present in your Project.

```
unit ControlInfoHandler;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Forms;

implementation

uses
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TControlInfoHandler = class( TComponent )
  private
    FCurrent :       TWinControl;
    FCurrentLength : Integer;
  protected
    procedure ActiveControlChange( Sender : TObject );
    procedure ApplicationIdle( Sender : TObject; var Done : Boolean );
    procedure Notification( AComponent : TComponent; Operation : TOperation ); override;
  end;

  THackedEdit = class( TCustomEdit )
  published
    property MaxLength;
  end;

var
  LControlInfoHandler : TControlInfoHandler;

  { TControlInfoHandler }

procedure TControlInfoHandler.ActiveControlChange( Sender : TObject );
begin
  FCurrent       := Screen.ActiveControl;
  FCurrentLength := 0;
  if Assigned( FCurrent )
  then
    FCurrent.FreeNotification( Self );
end;

procedure TControlInfoHandler.ApplicationIdle( Sender : TObject; var Done : Boolean );
var
  LEdit :   THackedEdit;
  LCanvas : TControlCanvas;
  LWidth :  Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned( FCurrent ) or not ( FCurrent is TCustomEdit )
  then
    Exit;

  LEdit := THackedEdit( FCurrent as TCustomEdit );

  if ( LEdit.MaxLength > 0 )
  then
    begin

      LCanvas         := TControlCanvas.Create;
      LCanvas.Control := LEdit;

      LCanvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
      LCanvas.Pen.Width := 2;

      LWidth := LEdit.Width - 6;

      if FCurrentLength <> LEdit.GetTextLen
      then
        begin
          LCanvas.Pen.Color := LEdit.Color;
          LCanvas.MoveTo( 0, LEdit.Height - 4 );
          LCanvas.LineTo( LWidth, LEdit.Height - 4 );
        end;

      LCanvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
      LWidth            := LWidth * LEdit.GetTextLen div LEdit.MaxLength;

      LCanvas.MoveTo( 0, LEdit.Height - 4 );
      LCanvas.LineTo( LWidth, LEdit.Height - 4 );

      FCurrentLength := LEdit.GetTextLen;

    end;
end;

procedure TControlInfoHandler.Notification( AComponent : TComponent; Operation : TOperation );
begin
  inherited;
  if ( FCurrent = AComponent ) and ( Operation = opRemove )
  then
    FCurrent := nil;
end;

initialization

LControlInfoHandler          := TControlInfoHandler.Create( Application );
Screen.OnActiveControlChange := LControlInfoHandler.ActiveControlChange;
Application.OnIdle           := LControlInfoHandler.ApplicationIdle;

end.
```