# Is there an easy way to make that the design of my readonly TEdit will be the same as my disabled TEdit?

Tags: delphi

how to make that the **design** (mostly font color) of my `TMyedit` (`TmyEdit = Class(Tedit)`) when they are in **readonly** will be exactly the same as if they was **disabled**?

Comment: I have similar problem. I want my disabled TEdits to look like the are readonly.

Comment: GetSysColor(COLOR_GRAYTEXT) is probably the font color but there's also the frame color change, not reacting to hot track and cursor difference. You probably don't want the default cursor though.

Comment: If your want a readonly Edit to look and act like a disabled Edit, then why not just disable it?

Comment: @nola - You can partly achieve that by parenting normal edits by a disabled container, e.g. a panel. They will be effectively disabled without setting the property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : because when the Tedit are disabled we can not copy the text :(

Comment: @Stephane when you set the Edit to read-only, you are just going to have to set is `Color` and `Font.Color` as needed. For instance, to `clBtnFace` and `clGrayText`, respectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : yes but this will erase the old value in Color / Font.Color and when user remove the readonly i will need to revert those value. I would like something like enabled=false do, i mean without touching the property of the Tedit

Comment: @Stephane so, obviously you will have to store the old values somewhere when you overwrite them, and then restore them later. What is hard about that? What you are asking for can't be done automatically, you need to write code for it

Comment: @RemyLebeau : yes sure i can store old value somewhere but i would prefere a way to just override the ondraw or something like this. storing the old value is not a big problem

Comment: @Stephane - I believe the frame is not of any system color but a theme part. In any case if you want to *over*paint the frame, I think you can do so in a wm_paint handler. Testing for *readonly* should suffice.

Comment: Call BeginPaint yourself in the handler, set the text color of the DC before passing on to default processing. E.g.: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53969909/243614), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409182/243614).